# Add MouseLeftButtonUp events dynamically

Tags: c#, wpf, events, addition

I've added the following 2 methods to the MainWindow.xml, but I can't fire the event

```
private void Button_Click_2(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    lstContacts.Items.Clear();
    cvMenuItem test = new cvMenuItem("test", Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("USERPROFILE") + @"\Downloads\images.jpg");
    test.MouseLeftButtonUp += new System.EventHandler(imClicked);
    lstContacts.Items.Add(test);
}

void imClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("hello");
}
```

I keep getting this error, why?

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.EventHandler' to
>   'System.Windows.Input.MouseButtonEventHandler'    MainWindow.xaml.cs  64  39  WpfApplication1

Comment: As the error message states, you are trying to add to `MouseLeftButtonUp` a `System.EventHandler` delegate whereas you are expected to add [MouseButtonEventHandler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebuttoneventhandler%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) wherein the delegate is expected to return `void` and have first parameter as `object` and second as `MouseButtonEventArgs`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
test.MouseLeftButtonUp += imClicked;


private void imClicked(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
             MessageBox.Show("hello");
    }
```